# the logic of lambda as return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

How to understand this code?
Can you explain the logic of this code step by step?
What is the logic of "a" argument in this "return lambda a : a * n" line of code?

```
def myfunc(n):
  return lambda a : a * n 

mydoubler = myfunc(2)

print(mydoubler(11))
```

Comment: Some helpful search terms for your future research. `myfunc` is a function which implements *curried* multiplication. To do so, it uses a `lambda` which is an *anonymous function*, and it creates a *closure* around the variable `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, `lambda`s are anonymous functions. The form of a `lambda` can be generalized to the following form:

`lambda arguments: expression`

So, I think rewriting the `lambda` in `myfunc()` will help you understand what's going on. If the `lambda` were to be rewritten as a function:

```
def myfunc(n):
    def lambda_as_func(a):
        return a * n
    return lambda_as_func
```

This snippet and your snippet, in essence, perform the same tasks: when `myfunc()` is called, a function is returned. The returned function takes one argument (`a`), which can be called later.

If you were to try it out:

```py
>>> def myfunc(n):
        def lambda_as_func(a):
            return a * n
        return lambda_as_func

>>> double = myfunc(2)
>>> double(11)
22
>>> double(50)
100
```

However, instead of defining another function within `myfunc()`, Python allows us to create `lambda_as_func()` as a one line function in the form as a `lambda`.

Answer (score 2):

`myfunc` returns a (lambda) function, this is just an unnamed function. The nameless function accepts one parameter, called `a` (yes, the function has no name, but its parameter is named). This nameless function accepts `a` and multiplies it by `n`, then returns the result.

`mydoubler` is a named instance of the unnamed (lambda) function, with the value 2 plugged into the parameter `a`. Each time you call `mydoubler` it uses the bound value for `a`, which is 2, and multiplies it by `n` as before, where `n` is the value 11.